# What happens if I set low Gwei while sending ether

Tags: ether, gas, ico

I was trying to participate in an ico. They recommended we set Gwei at 99 and gas limit at 200000. Well my client has the default set to Wei so I made the mistake of setting 99 Wei instead of 99 Gwei. My transaction on etherscan states estimated confirmation time is a very long time. ICO is already closed so that doesn't matter. My question is will this transaction ever clear or fail and probably have my ether reverted back or that ether is gone?

Tx Hash `0x5391c7e07256e62d4ef861bc8156a7d0b7f7c0e4dac02beee441275809cf2672`

Comment: I wanted to transfer ERC20 tokens to transfer from metamask to exchange. However I accidentally set 2 gwei, which was very low. Now my transaction is pending and it doesn't showing up in myetherwallet as a pending status. Can this transaction be automatically cancelled or I have to do something? (transaction is not showing up, so I am not able to replace or cancel it)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26936)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may more not not get mined, but it's fairly unlikely. If the transaction is never mined, then you wont lose your Ether because it hasn't left your wallet. If you want to "cancel" (cancel really means replace a tx with one that just sends to yourself), you can read the guide on [here](https://myetherwallet.github.io/knowledge-base/transactions/check-status-of-ethereum-transaction.html). Basically what you're doing is replacing the transaction with another transaction with the same nonce and a higher gas price, and sending the eth to your own address. This makes the original transaction invalid.

Comment: Thanks for linking to the guide. I was able to replace my transaction erroneously sent with a very low gas price and gas limit.